# Не работает iconContent

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```
setFeatureFormat = (point, icon="circle", iconImageSize=DEFAULT_ICON_IMAGE_SIZE) => {
  const { lat, lon, offers } = point;
  const ids = offers.map(offer => offer.id);

  return {
    type: 'Feature',
    id: ids,
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [lat, lon],
    }, 
    properties: {
      balloonContent: "Содержимое балуна",
      iconContent: '11',
      hintContent: "Текст подсказки"
    },
    options: {
      iconLayout: 'default#image',
      iconImageHref: 
        `/src/PriceAnalize/OfferAnalyticsMap/img/${icon}.svg`,
      iconImageSize
    }
  }
};
```

Использую кастомные иконки для отображения точек на карте, для отображения использую objectManager, даже если я убираю свойство для кастомной иконки, цифра в маркере все равно не отображается. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default#image это вариант макета без контента. Используйте default#imageWithContent - он с контентом